# ¿Como mandar un valor de bucle for a otra función?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un bucle `for` en el que asigno un nombre+numero a todos los `input` que yo cree.

```
addInpt(e){
      var tag = e.target;
      var sib = tag.parentNode;


      var lgn = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-index="2"]');
      
         for (var i = 0; i < lgn.length+1; i++){
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.setAttribute("data-index",2);
            input.name = "plus_"+i;
               var tag_p = e.target;
               var sib_p = tag_p.parentNode;
         }
         sib_p.appendChild(input);
      }
```

Hago `target` del botón pulsado, veo su `parentNode`, y agrego un `input` como `appendChild`, dicho `input` tendrá el nombre `"plus_"+i`

`i` está sacada del bucle `for`, y ahora necesito insertar dicho valor `i` dentro de otras funciones:

```
// Fragmento de código donde insertaría el valor i del bucle for de antes

if(!energy.querySelector("[name=plus_"/*AQUI IRÍA EL VALOR I*/)){} else{
                        energy.querySelector("[name=plus_").value=eng.plus;
                     }
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para traspasar dicho valor?

Comment: y el error o incombeniente en tu codigo cual vendria a ser?

Comment: En esas otras funciones, ¿cómo o por qué intentas acceder a esos campos, se ejecutan por algún evento? Por favor edita la pregunta para explicar todo el contexto y agregar un ejemplo de alguna de esas funciones.